# Can someone tell me why my variable will not store?

Tags: java

I have triple checked everything and I can't find out why my score (s) variable is not storing in my Move class file. After messing around with it for awhile I think i narrowed it down to the class file but I really am not too sure. I just would like someone to look it over and see if there are any obvious solutions.

As you can see all I am trying to do is make a simple 2048 game for my own practice. It should be pretty straight forward. Thanks for helping me out this has been stumping me for weeks any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is the main file: it prints the board and spawns a random new number.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game2048 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    int inp = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int zc = 0;

    System.out.println("+------------------------------------------------------------------+");

    //welcome message
    while(inp != 1){
        System.out.println("2408 Game");
        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println("1 To start!");
        System.out.println("2. Help.");
        inp = scn.nextInt();

        if(inp == 2){
            System.out.println("wsad are their respective controls.");
            System.out.println("Try to make 2048!");
            System.out.println("Press and number to continue.");
            inp = scn.nextInt();
        }
    }

    //initializing game board
    Move move = new Move();
    drawBoard(move);
    while(end == 0){
        move(move, scn.next());
        spawn(move.getBoard());
        drawBoard(move);
    }
    System.out.println("You lost sucka");

}
public static Move move(Move mM, String m){ //Sends move keys to move class
    if(m.equals("w")){ 
        mM.moveUp(mM.getBoard(), mM.getScore());
    }
    if(m.equals("s")){ 
        mM.moveDown(mM.getBoard(), mM.getScore());
    }
    if(m.equals("a")){
        mM.moveLeft(mM.getBoard(), mM.getScore());
    }
    if(m.equals("d")){
        mM.moveRight(mM.getBoard(), mM.getScore());
    }
    return mM;
}
public static int[][] spawn(int[][] b){ //spawns 2 or 4 in a random block
    Random rand = new Random();

    int x = rand.nextInt(4);
    int y = rand.nextInt(4);
    int c = rand.nextInt(9);

    while(b[x][y]!=0){
        x = rand.nextInt(4);
        y = rand.nextInt(4);
    }
    if(c==9){
        b[x][y]=4;
    }else b[x][y]=2;

    return b;
}
public static void drawBoard(Move m){ //draws board
    int[][] b = m.getBoard();
    System.out.println("+-------------------------------------+");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("|   "+b[0][0]+"    |    "+b[1][0]+"    |    "+b[2][0]+"    |    "+b[3][0]+"    |");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("|   "+b[0][1]+"    |    "+b[1][1]+"    |    "+b[2][1]+"    |    "+b[3][1]+"    |");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("|   "+b[0][2]+"    |    "+b[1][2]+"    |    "+b[2][2]+"    |    "+b[3][2]+"    |");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("|   "+b[0][3]+"    |    "+b[1][3]+"    |    "+b[2][3]+"    |    "+b[3][3]+"    |");
    System.out.println("|        |         |         |         |");
    System.out.println("+-------------------------------------+");
    System.out.println(m.getScore());
}
}
```

Here is the Move class which handles all the board moves and (supposedly) the score.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class Move {
private int[][] b = new int[4][4];
private int s = 0;

public Move(){ //initialized a new board with two 2's randomly placed on board
    Random rand = new Random();

    int x = rand.nextInt(4);
    int y = rand.nextInt(4);
    int x1 = rand.nextInt(4);
    int y1 = rand.nextInt(4);

    while(x == x1 && y == y1){ //makes sure the numbers are not   placed in the same block
        x = rand.nextInt(4);
    }

    b[x][y]=2;
    b[x1][y1]=2;
}
/*public Move(){
    b[0][0]=8;
    b[0][1]=4;
    b[0][2]=2;
    b[0][3]=2;

    b[2][0]=2;
    b[2][1]=2;
    b[2][3]=2;

    b[3][0]=2;
    b[3][1]=2;
    b[3][2]=2;
}*/
public int[][] getBoard(){
    return b;
}
public int getScore(){
    return s;
}
public void moveUp(int[][] b, int s){ 
    int c;
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
            c = 1;                      
            while(b[x][y]==0 && (c+y)<4){
                if(b[x][y+c]!=0){
                    b[x][y]=b[x][y+c];
                    b[x][y+c]=0;
                }else c++;
            }c = 2;
            while(b[x][y+1]==0 && (c+y)<4){
                if(b[x][y+c]!=0){
                    b[x][y+1]=b[x][y+c];
                    b[x][y+c]=0;
                }else c++;
            }if(b[x][y]==b[x][y+1]){
                b[x][y]+=b[x][y+1];
                b[x][y+1]=0;
                s+=b[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
public void moveDown(int[][] b, int s){ 
    int c;
    for(int y = 3; y > 0; y--){
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
            c = 1;                      
            while(b[x][y]==0 && c <= y){
                if(b[x][y-c]!=0){
                    b[x][y]=b[x][y-c];
                    b[x][y-c]=0;
                }else c++;
            }c = 2;
            while(b[x][y-1]==0 && c <= y){
                if(b[x][y-c]!=0){
                    b[x][y-1]=b[x][y-c];
                    b[x][y-c]=0;
                }else c++;
            }if(b[x][y]==b[x][y-1]){
                b[x][y]+=b[x][y-1];
                b[x][y-1]=0;
                s+=b[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
}
public void moveLeft(int[][] b, int s){ 
    int c;
    for(int y = 0; y < 4;y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 3;x++){
            c=2;
            while(b[x+1][y]==0 && (c+x)<4){
                if(b[x+c][y]!=0){
                    b[x+1][y]=b[x+c][y];
                    b[x+c][y]=0;
                }else c++;
            }if(b[x][y]==b[x+1][y]){
                b[x][y]+=b[x+1][y];
                b[x+1][y]=0;
                s+=b[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
}
public void moveRight(int[][] b, int s){ 
    int c;
    for(int y = 0; y < 4;y++){
        for(int x = 3; x > 0;x--){
            c = 1;                      
            while(b[x][y]==0 && c <= x){
                if(b[x-c][y]!=0){
                    b[x][y]=b[x-c][y];
                    b[x-c][y]=0;
                }else c++;
            }c=2;
            while(b[x-1][y]==0 && c <= x){
                if(b[x-c][y]!=0){
                    b[x-1][y]=b[x-c][y];
                    b[x-c][y]=0;
                }else c++;
            }if(b[x][y]==b[x-1][y]){
                b[x][y]+=b[x-1][y];
                b[x-1][y]=0;
                s+=b[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [The answer to your problem is here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The board and the score are member variables of the `Move` class. When you instantiate the `Move` class that `Move Object` now has a specific board and score associated with it. You don't need to pass these member varibles into the class because they are now inherently part of the object which you can access using the `this` keyword within the `Move` class's member functions. You just need to operate on the object members. so it would just be like `myMoveObj.moveUp()`

And in your function

```
public void moveDown(){ 
                //other code here
                this.s+=this.b[x][y];
            }
```

Comment: so you are saying to move up I would only need this in the main `if(m.equals("w")){ mM.moveUp();}` and `public void moveUp(){ }` in the move class if i just mention `this.b[x][y]` or `this.s` ?

Comment: Without the method params `this.` that is redundant @imaoreo.

Comment: @stazima Thanks this finally fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I got the right explanation for your problem:

- you are passing the current score via calls of `mM.getScore()` to the moveXXX methods for an update.
- Inside the moveXXX method a method-local variable `s` is declared (as in i.e. `public void moveRight(int[][] b, int s)`). This one overshadows the `s` that you defined inside your class.
- When doing an update on `s` (e.g. the addition `s+=b[x][y];`), `s`  refers to the method local-field.
- After leaving the method, this update is "lost". And there was no change at all to the score defined at class level.